# Não estou conseguindo capturar os vários itens selecionados no select2, como fazer?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-select2

Não estou conseguindo capturar os vários itens selecionados no select2, como fazer?
Meu objetivo será capturar estes itens e envia-los para um Textbox, o que estou utilizando ?

Uma lista, veja a seguir:

```
<asp:ListBox id="lb" 
         runat="server" 
         class="form-control input-sm select2-multiple" 
         Width="70%" 
         multiple>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Administração</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Administração Pública</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Agronegócios e Agropecuária</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Como estou tentando fazer ?

```
protected void Btn_Teste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    string message = "";
    foreach (ListItem item in lb.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
           message += item.Text ;
        }
    }
    TextBox.Text = message;
}
```

Do jeito que estou fazendo está voltando somente o primeiro item selecionado?

Comment: Do jeito que estou fazendo está voltando somente o primeiro item selecionado

Comment: Dá uma lida no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site

Answer (score -1):

Foi configurado errado o componente, não é um atributo comum, é uma propriedade com o nome de `SelectionMode` onde o seu padrão de configuração é `Single` mas, precisa ser `Multiple` para que a seleção seja múltipla (`multiple`).

```
SelectionMode="Multiple"
```

Segue o exemplo completo:

```
<asp:ListBox
    ID="lb"
    runat="server"
    class="js-example-basic-single"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Administração</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Administração Pública</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Agronegócios e Agropecuária</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

***Bonus:***

Para recuperar os valores e até mesmo o texto segue o exemplo de código:

```
// Recupera os indices selecionados
int[] indices = lb.GetSelectedIndices();
foreach (int indice in indices)
{
    //recupera o texto 
    lb.Items[indice].Text
    //recupera o valor
    lb.Items[indice].Value; 
}
```

o método `GetSelectedIndices()` recupera os índices que estão selecionados e para que recupere os valores selecionados precisa acessar `indice` do método `Items` e nele tem a propriedade `Text` (*que é o valor da caixa selecionada*) e `Value` (*que é valor da caixa selecionada*), acho mais performática por não ter que varrer todo o seus itens. *A forma que está na sua pergunta funciona, mas, o desempenho é comprometido por ter obrigação de passar em todos os itens*.

---

<sup>**Referencias:**</sup>

- [ListBox Classe](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox?view=netframework-4.8)
- [ListBox.SelectionMode Propriedade](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Então amigo dev do jeito que estou declarando e chamando a lista e select2 funciona, é selecionado os vários itens, porém na hora de capturar que não estou conseguindo. Utilizei o seu método que recupera, porém quando pressiono o botão dá o postback só pega um e o pior quando dá o postback os que foram selecionados somem e só aparece o primeiro

Comment: A lista como vc colocou não funciona pra mim, creio que seja uma outra versão de componente. Tem como colocar o código inteiro com suas referências pra eu testar aqui

Comment: @FábioMedeirosBitencourt você não está sabendo fazer cara... Esse código é funcional e é assim que faz, agora se fez uma resposta baseada na minha !?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui meus amigos DEV com a dica do Virgilio Novic, só fiz algumas algumas modificações
Substitui a lista pelo select(HTML)

```html
   <select id="lb" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm select2-multiple" multiple>
    <option value=" 1 "> Administração </option>
<option value=" 2 "> Administração Pública </option>
<option value=" 3 "> Agronegócios e Agropecuária </option>
<option value=" 4 "> Ciências Aeronáuticas </option>
                        </select>
```

No .cs coloquei o seguinte código.

```
 string mensagem="";

    for (int i = 0; i <= lb.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (lb.Items[i].Selected)
            mensagem +=  lb.Items[i].Text ;
    }
```

Agora é só transferi a váriavel mensagem para o Textbox.

Comment: Se fez a mesma coisa que eu, só que não usou o componente da `ToolBox`, vale lembrar que a minha resposta é de acordo com a pergunta e mediante os princípios ideais para desenvolvimento e o que você acabou de fazer funciona, mas, não está certo. O grande problema é que você fez errado porque não configurou `ListBox` corretamente e por isso do problema.